# sign up form does not work

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I'm new to php and I was trying to make a simple registration form using php and mysql.
I have followed a tutorial but it does not seem to work. 
Here is my code:

**con.php**

```
<?php
    $host = "******";
    $user = "******";
    $pass = "******";
    $db   = '******';

    $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die('could not connect to database.');

    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die('could not find database');
?>
```

**register.php**

```
<?php
    include "con.php";
    $username = $_POST['user_name'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $first    = $_POST['first'];
    $last     = $_POST['last'];
    $insert   = "insert into users (user_name,password,first,last) values(".$username.",".$password.",".$first.",".$last.")";
    mysql_query($insert) or die("Sorry could not complete signup");
    echo 'Signup succsessfull';
?>
```

**HTML**

```
    <form action='register.php' method='post'>
        <div style='color:orange;'>First name:</div>
        <input type='text' name='first' value='<?php if(isset($_POST["first"])){echo $_POST["first"];}?>'>
        <div style='color:orange;'>Last name:</div>
        <input type='text' name='last' value='<?php if(isset($_POST["last"])){echo $_POST["last"];}?>'>
        <div style='color:orange;'>User name:</div>
        <input type='text' name='user_name' value='<?php if(isset($_POST["user_name"])){echo $_POST["user_name"];}?>'>
        <div style='color:orange;'>Password:</div>
        <input type='password' name='password'>
        <input type='reset' value='Reset'>
        <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
    </form>
```

It would be great if someone could help figure this out because I can't.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: You are also [vulnerable to XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: Use PDO, it's actually pretty simple.

Comment: So what's not working ?! (Besides the whole hacker's sweet dream...)

Comment: What result do you get? How does that differ from the result you expect?

Comment: You should specifiy in more detail what is "not working". What have you tried to make it work etc.?

Answer (score 2):

```
$insert = "insert into users (user_name,password,first,last) values(".$username.",".$password.",".$first.",".$last.")";
```

String values in SQL have to be quoted. You aren't quoting your data.

Move to using prepared statements and bound variables as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/19068) and the database API will take care of adding the quotes for you.

Comment: Also, this "echo 'Signup succsessfull';" just outputs signup successful, it doesn't tell you if the insert was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to as below

```
$insert = "insert into users (user_name,password,first,last) values('".$username."','".$password."','".$first."','".$last."')";
```

I think you have selectd varchar datatype of field, so you have to add single quotes to every variable.